# When are predicates appropriate and what is the best pattern for usage

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, predicate

When are predicates appropriate and what is the best pattern for usage? What are the advantages of predicates?

It seems to me like most cases where a predicate can be employed a tight loop would accomplish the same functionality?

I don’t see a reusability argument given you will probably only implement a predicate in one method right?

They look and feel nice but besides that they seem like you would only employ them when you need a quick hack on the collection classes?

**UPDATE**

But why would you be rewriting the tight loop again and again?

In my mind/code when it comes to collections I always end up with something like

```
Class Person
End Class

Class PersonList
    Inherits List(Of Person)

    Function FindByName(Name) as Person
         tight loop....
    End Function
End Class
```

@Ani

By that same logic I could implement the method as such

```
Class PersonList
    Inherits List(Of Person)

    Function FindByName(Name) as PersonList
    End Function

    Function FindByAge(Age) as PersonList
    End Function

    Function FindBySocialSecurityNumber(SocialSecurityNumber) as PersonList
    End Function
End Class
```

And call it as such

```
Dim res as PersonList = MyList.FindByName("Max").FindByAge(25).FindBySocialSecurityNumber(1234)
```

and the result along with the amount of code and its reusability is largely the same, no?

**I am not arguing just trying to understand.**

Comment: Why would you use SQL instead of walking the tables yourself in a tight loop? It looks and feels nice but besides that seems like you would only employ it when you need a quick hack on a database.

Comment: (In reponse to your update) - For a realistic scenario, why not *implement* the tight loop? Also, why not write `FindByName`, `FindByAge`, `FindBySocialSecurityNumber`? What if the user then wants to find people between 24 and 34 years of age? Can you write every possible filter? What if the loop logic were more complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the key benefits of predicates is composability.  For example, in my natural language project I have complex date time queries created from natural language input e.g. 'every thursday in May 2010' that become database queries created by composing a series of predicates.

Predicates become even more powerful when combined with Expressions as the processing can be deferred until runtime and possibly even handed off to some other system to execute (e.g. Linq to Entities).

Predicates are also key to functional programming.

Comment: +1  If a dev has never done any functional programming, they don't readily understand the concepts of pipelining and functions as data in when coding.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me like most cases where
>   a predicate can be employed a tight
>   loop would accomplish the same
>   functionality?

The idea is that you're going to be writing that same "tight" loop over and over again in "same-same but different" scenarios, varying *just* the "condition" part of it. Why not use the framework's built in ability to specify that condition in a succint manner, pass that as an argument to the "looping" method and be done with it?

Answer (score 1):

The idea/pattern behind using predicates is when you need to apply a set of conditions to a set of data to transform the data.  You can write a loop to accomplish the same end goal, but typically you are simply interrogating the data for some set of conditions and then collecting the qualifying pieces of it in a list.  By using the frameworks ability to support predicates, a new developer extending your code doesn't have to recreate the mechanics used to collect the qualified data.